# What are the commonly accepted guidelines specific to this site (2015)?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

At [Folklore or official policy?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/folklore-or-official-policy), I wrote, "I feel like I've come into the movie theater in the middle of the movie. Please, help me understand what's going on in this site and what is expected of me."

Highlighting some material from that thread:

> We write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.  [Such-and-so] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.
>
> As for formal or official policies, it seems to me Stack Exchange has a relative lack of them.
>
> The closest thing to formal policies that I know of are the documentation in the Help Center, and the mechanics of the site itself.
>
> SE etiquette is that meta questions are about an issue, not a user, so names are usually left out of questions on meta to avoid making it about a particular user.

Also, today I read

> this site has a policy of not discussing poetry

at [meaning of "trailing clouds of glory"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268802/meaning-of-trailing-clouds-of-glory).

I'd like to assume that the goal is *not* to set up a mine field for newcomers trying to make meaningful contributions to this site.  So let's be constructive.  I would like to invite users in the know to help me assemble **a compendium of generally accepted guidelines/conventions to this site**.  Answers would be preferred over Comments.  I'd appreciate it if you would avoid bringing up anything potentially controversial here.  (You could always create a different question in Meta about a particular item or set of items.)  Also note, this question isn't about mechanics.

---

Here's another one: [A word to mean the act of making two things equivalent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269677/a-word-to-mean-the-act-of-making-two-things-equivalent/270071#270071)

> Please set mentions in italic.

This is also confusing.  I see many people setting their word or phrase proposals in bold.

---

I found another one!

> '‘If we accept the axiom that trivial [/very basic] questions are bad
> for the site, then the proper response to [such] a ... question is:
> 1.Don't answer! 2… [Vote] to close. The point is not to encourage trivial [/very basic] questions. If you post an answer or vote up an
> existing answer, you're implicitly encouraging more questions like
> it.’

(taken from https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270603/can-i-use-they-for-non-living-things)

Comment: This is a comment because it's not an additional policy to be documented in a formal answer: the [help/on-topic] does say that interpretation / lit-crit is expressly off-topic. Though that topic clearly covers both poetry and lyrics (and anything else hat requires subjective *interpretation*), I do wish it more explicitly called out those two topics. One issue is that HS curricula in the US (at least) conflate language and literature (so visitors to the site have an preconceived expectation that we'll discuss literature). Another problematic influence is Yahoo! Answers & its love of lyrics.

Comment: See also [*What questions are on-topic and off-topic here?*](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/273/55623) which is supplementary to and more descriptive than the [help/on-topic].

Comment: We already *have* "a compendium of generally accepted guidelines to this site". It's called the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) (or FAQ). So I think this question is "redundant".

Comment: Did you miss the part about searching meta and reading meta answers? We don't need to do this. This is something *you* want. If you want to learn the culture, read the answers to your questions and learn.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/memes-of-english-language-usage

Comment: *Searching "answers in comments" will get you 676 results, of which the top few should provide a lot of insight* (from the Folklore thread) - 676 is a lot of results to look at, especially when some of them may be obsolete, and there is a lot of discussion to wade through.  Also, for rules or conventions I'm not aware of, I wouldn't even know what to google.

Comment: Searching the site is different than googling. Searching the site is helpful, and you only need to read a few posts to learn a *lot*. You have plenty of rep on multiple sites, which means you're not ignorant of the system. Stack Exchange (including this site) is not broken. Please learn how to use the site. The down votes on your questions should inform you of *something*.

Comment: @aparente001 For a "starter kit", so to speak, of rules and conventions that you probably want to be aware of, check out the two links I offered in my second comment.

Comment: I can follow the rules if I know what the rules are.  I would really like to see folks collaborate on *writing them down*.

Comment: Clearly you would, but it isn't going to happen just because you would really like it. That's the whole gist of my comments. Look at your answer score and try to understand that you have 0 votes for and -4 against the suggestion.

Comment: Also, your latest edit appears to be incomplete. However, there is a difference between a single-word request being answered in bold, or a specific word being emboldened for emphasis in a question, and a simple use-mention distinction in bold rather than italic. I don't think I've seen that, so if you have a genuine example, that would be interesting.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I didn't quite follow the three different situations you mentioned, but here's where this came up: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269677/a-word-to-mean-the-act-of-making-two-things-equivalent/270071#270071

Comment: @AndrewLeach it can't have escaped your attention that a user has been doing a lot of editing recently, one of the user's peeves are words in bold type, which are replaced in italics. Not every answer that contains a word in bold type is edited, but...  I suggest you back track a few pages and check the history of some of these recently edited posts.

Comment: I'm curious; are you going to continue to edit this question indefinitely until every question you have about the site is addressed? Is this your way of assembling "**a compendium of generally accepted guidelines/conventions to this site.**"?

Comment: I would much rather that experienced users contributed meaningful answers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, The problem is that [there're many things missing from the help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269677/a-word-to-mean-the-act-of-making-two-things-equivalent/270071#comment610514_270071). If the help center had had all the info, this thread wouldn't've appeared in the first place.

Comment: @DanBron, The thread *"What questions are on-topic and off-topic here"* is answering **one** policy. What about the other policies that are specific to this site? ([cf.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/159916))

Comment: @medica, That was **exactly** how the community did it. As can be seen from the revisions of the thread linked by the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

## *“Please set mentions in italic”*

Let me address the ﬁnal point.

Yes, some people do set mentions in bold, but I really wish they wouldn’t. For the past ﬁve years, ELU editors have followed [this simple standard](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/364) posted by nohat♦ on October 15<sup>th</sup> 2010 at 8:05pm:

> I usually use *italics*. Sometimes I use “double quotation marks” when referring to long phrases or whole sentences. I would stay away from **bold**, `verbatim`, or plain.

His policy offers these advantages at the least:

1. It is the top-voted answer to the meta question about the matter. In the absence of explicit directives to the contrary, this therefore represents community consensus on site policy.
2. Although it is one member’s preference and style, it was posted by one of our moderators, and this cannot help but carry some guiding weight.
3. It is short, simple, and to the point. This makes it easy to remember and to apply.
4. It has been there for ﬁve years as of this writing, setting long-standing precedent.
5. It’s the standard used by dictionaries and professional linguistics journals, and is therefore the appropriate one on a site whose charter is “for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”.
6. Those of us who do the most [editing](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) have been consistently following this standard as long as the site has existed.  This helps give our site a well-groomed look.
7. It is typographically *inoffensive*, because the overall color (how much black, basically) of the Georgia italic face matches that of the Georgia roman one, allowing the page to look professionally put together.
8. It presents a uniﬁed [page color](http://practicaltypography.com/color.html), which is highly desirable. Interrupting the smooth texture of the paired roman and italic with inline super-heavyweight bold scattered randomly about the page destroys that simple elegance.
9. The default font weight all browsers give to bold in the absence of CSS to reduce it is much too heavy a weight to look tidy.  Without a CSS hack which our style sheet does not have, we suffer a ponderous and plodding default bold weight that no publisher worthy of the name would ever dare set down in print.
10. Bold used for things other than headers* leaves the page looking too ***SHOUTY***, as though it were a cheap supermarket tabloid, a seven-year-old’s workbook, or a **`ransom`** ***`note`***.  It isn’t nice to be yelled at by a noisy page.
11. To give the occasional point special emphasis, the skilled writer competent at his craft need use nothing but the English language itself — rather than tawdry typographical blunderbusses.

That’s plenty enough to convince me. I only hope it also persuades others.

---

<sub>* And even then you should rely on point size allowing the weight to scale proportionately.</sub>

Comment: **WOW** *cool* `ᴘᴏsᴛ`! 

Comment: There are cases where the single-word answer is typed in italic but because it is in a long post, people do not notice it. I see no harm in placing that key word or short phrase in bold type in a lengthy post. If nothing else it stops people from suggesting duplicate answers. I think a little individualism is permissible, EL&U is not a volume, it is made up thousands of different users who have their own quirks and styles. This doesn't mean I advocate titles in CAPS, or ***entire paragraphs in italicized bold type***, there has to be limits otherwise the site would indeed look chaotic.

Comment: As for @nohat simple style guide; it is useful, it is very sensible, it is aesthetically pleasing but *533  views* in four years hardly represents  a unanimous  "community consensus".

Comment: @MariLouA Single-word answers are frowned upon. :) Seriously, even the attention-deficited, video-gamed, sound-byted generation is expected to read an answer. Italic jumps right out at you without screaming. Maybe on a phone this is different, but on the real site it looks nice. And yes, I do think this represents consensus; meta votes not page views are how we measure these things. In any event, I intend to remain tasteful and encourage others to do the same.

Comment: SE cares about the number of views a post has, a post that attracts less than two hundred views in two years suggests that people are not interested in that question. But a post that has attracted 20,000 views in two years suggests that visitors share the same problem. If these visitors do not post a question themselves it is because they found the answers posted satisfactory. Finally, there are badges for the number of views a post attracts; 1,000 (bronze), 2,500 (silver), 10,000 (gold).  SE does measure views, [*eccome*](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/eccome)!

Comment: @Mari-LouA [Meta posts and votes on them define policy, in that (insofar as Stack Exchange allows) the community decides how it should operate.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7053)

Comment: So how are we to judge the single upvote your answer has so received?